# PHP get array value from function

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function telephoneNums($telephoneNum) {
    $telephoneNum = trim($telephoneNum);
    $telephoneNum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $telephoneNum);

    if($telephoneNum !=8){
        $errorMsg[] = 'The contact number must be exactly 8 charators long';
    }


    return $telephoneNum;
    return array_values($errorMsg[]);
}
```

I am managing to return $telephoneNum but I am not managing to return $errorMsg[] - I am getting the following error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading`

I also tried `return $errorMsg[];` but I still get the same errors.

How can I return `$errorMsg[]`

Comment: Why you just dont use the `echo`? like example : `echo 'The contact number must be exactly 8 charators long';`

Comment: `$errorMsg[] = 'foo'` works as the equivilant to `array_push($errorMsg, 'foo');`. You only use empty brackets (`[]`) when adding items to the array.

Comment: I need to output the $errorMsg[] outside of the function

Answer (score 1):

check below solution

```
function telephoneNums($telephoneNum) {
    $telephoneNum = trim($telephoneNum);
    $telephoneNum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $telephoneNum);
    $op=Array();
    $op['telephoneNum']=$telephoneNum;
    $op['errorMsg']='';
    if($telephoneNum !=8){
        $op['errorMsg']='The contact number must be exactly 8 charators long';
    }

    return $op;

}

$out_put = telephoneNums('12345');
echo $out_put['telephoneNum'];
echo $out_put['errorMsg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like

```
return array_values($errorMsg);
```

And you also having `return` statement before this line.Try to return at once.In your case after the first return statement it won't return the second value.

Also just initialize the `$errorMsg` like

```
$errorMsg = array();
```

If your `IF` condition not satisfies then at least it should be initialized with empty value or as an array.

Comment: Also you have to initialize it as I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like this using an array makes no sense, just use `$errMsg`. If it "must" be an array assign to an index and read by using the index, i.e. `$errMsg[0]`.

Plus: second `return` will never be reached.

If you want to return both values you could do it like this:

```
$result['phoneNum'] = '1234';
$result['errMsg'] = 'Whatever';

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` returns an array if the subject parameter is an array, or a string otherwise. And use `preg_match` instead.

```
function telephoneNums($telephoneNum) {
    $telephoneNum = trim($telephoneNum);
    $telephoneNum = preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $telephoneNum);

    if($telephoneNum[0] !=8){
        $errorMsg[] = 'The contact number must be exactly 8 charators long';
    }


    return $telephoneNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in your logic. I'll try to rewrite.

```
function telephoneNums($telephoneNum) {
//    $telephoneNum = trim($telephoneNum); // useless because of next line
    $telephoneNum = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $telephoneNum);

    $errorMsg = array(); // initialize
    if(strlen($telephoneNum) !=8){ // you need to check length but a value
        $errorMsg[] = 'The contact number must be exactly 8 charators long';
    }

    // you cannot return value twice. 
    if (!sizeof($errorMsg)) // You need to decide what value you want to return
       return $telephoneNum; 
    else
       return $errorMsg; // there is no reason to use array_values.
}
```